# What is the best way to deal with a question which is a duplicate of a question from another SE site?

Tags: discussion

So, yeah. The key phrase is "from another SE site". Today I found [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32365/quantization-of-electron-angular-momentum-in-bohr-model) on Chemistry.SE and I think that it quite close to [this answered(!) question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86534/what-made-bohr-quantise-angular-momentum-and-not-some-other-quantity) on Physics.SE. I'm not yet convinced that this two questions are duplicates of each other, but for the sake of argument lets us assume that they are. In fact, this is not the first time I came across a question which is already answered at Physics.SE.

I couldn't vote to close the question on Chemistry.SE as a duplicate since it requires the duplicate to be on Chemistry.SE and not somewhere else. What would be the best way then of handling such cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the question is on topic here. **Leave a comment with a link. And/Or write up an answer of your own, where you can link the other question.** This is true for questions, that are unintentional duplicates, not cross-posts. Apart from that there is currently not more to do.

There are a couple of discussions on this topic on meta. The so far most interesting IMO is the [cross-over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/260760) questions feature request. [Linking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16703/260760) them has been discussed. Even [closing them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151729/260760) was proposed.

I think [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/260760) is mainly focussed on cross-posting. If you find examples where the *same* post is asked in different communities, leave a comment with the link and ask the OP to either make them noticeable different from each other, or delete one post. (This is best done on both questions.) If nothing happens you can vote to close (custom) or flag for moderator interference.